# Python - questionable json response

Tags: python, json

I am very new to python and attempting to parse through what appears to be JSON data.

```
import requests
import json

URL = "http://myip/cgi-bin/lun/luci/;stok=/login?form=login"

payload = {
'operation': 'login',
'username': 'someuser',
'password': 'somepassword'
}

session = requests.session()
r = requests.post(URL, data=payload)

print (r.json())
```

What I get back is:

```
{u'data': {u'stok': u'0c2f16c954cd2cafccfaf1bf50000ac6'}, u'success': True}
```

I need to use the random collection of letters/numbers in the single quote `0c2f16c954cd2cafccfaf1bf50000ac6` (it changes every time).  I dont see any double quotes in this response. So a few questions:

1. I dont see any double quotes in the response.  Is this still json?
2. What would be the best way to assign that middle part of random characters to a variable so I can use it in a request url I need to build next?

Comment: not pretty sure but isn't it return a `dict` instance? (decoded json)

Comment: The `json()` method does not return JSON as the name would imply. It returns the **parsed** JSON data already.

Comment: And just a hint: If you start learning Python, start with Python 3, version 2 is shortly before retirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont see any double quotes in the response. Is this still json?

It *was* JSON.  `r.json()` deserialized the JSON response to a Python `dict`, and then `print` printed that `dict`.

> What would be the best way to assign that middle part of random characters to a variable so I can use it in a request url I need to build next?

```
a_variable = r.json()["data"]["stok"]
```